# Font-size in em .calculation accuracy

Tags: css, font-size

In one  template I saw 
All dimensions font-size are given by em.

```
footer p {
    font-size:0.8571428571428571em; /* 12px/14px */
}
```

Excuse me, but it is good practice ? 
What are the alternatives ?

Perhaps incorrect rounding font-size when zooming page ?

Comment: I round all my `em` and `rem` values to two decimal digits: `0.86`

Answer (score 0):

that em percentage looks like a division from a previous recent pixel value,
maybe the theme author substituted all pixel value at the end of the template development;

anyway I don't know of any cons to having an em value like that.